# How to intercept AsQueryable() of mongodb c# driver 2.x?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have a wrapper class for `IMongoCollection<T>` Collection.
I expose a function for `AsQueryable()`:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> AsQueryable()
{
    return Collection.AsQueryable();
}
```

I need to intercept the execution of queries (start and end of the query)
e.g. to catch errors and general logging or log long queries execution times.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is the guidance of my answer @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806029/how-to-track-mongodb-requests-from-a-console-application/41812814#41812814 of any help?

Comment: Hello Peter, thanks a lot, your answer definitely gives me valuable ideas and links to explore.

Comment: I found few other related questions:


How do I log my queries in MongoDB C# Driver 2.0?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/30333925/1544054


, and
MongoDB C# Driver: Query interceptors? https://stackoverflow.com/q/48947260/1544054